# How will ASP.NET AJAX be licensed?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

It would be very useful if somebody could indicate what the plans are for releasing and licensing the AJAX extensions.
The EULA for Beta 2 states that the software may be used for development and for web site deployment only. Redistribution is explicitly forbidden.
Does that imply that it is going to be released under terms different from the .NET framework and ASP.NET or is it just a precaution to prevent developers shipping the Beta?
It seems too risky to include AJAX in new products before there is some indication what the model is going to be....

Comment: Which specific product are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the ASP.Net AJAX Library...

It is now pat of the [CodePlex Foundation](http://codeplex.org/) (the first project in it).  Future releases at least as of now will use their open-source New BSD license, you can find it here: http://ajax.codeplex.com/license

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about the AJAX Control Toolkit. http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/license

AJAX comes out of the box with Visual Studio 2008+

In case you want to get the real information, I would advise open a support ticket with Microsoft. That will be safest!